# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter out a list of students based on the input value. But I've been getting an error saying "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {city, company, email, firstName, grades, id, lastName, pic, skill}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." I've tried using "Object.assign([], this.state.filteredStudents)" it still didn't work. I'm trying to display information that is contained in an array but in separate objects.

```
<div className="container">
          <input 
            id="search"
            name="search"
            onChange={this.handleInput} 
            placeholder="Search by name" 
            style={{width: '100%', border: '0', padding: '15px 0 7px 10px'}} 
          />
          <hr />
          {/* {allStudents} */}
          {this.state.search === "" ? allStudents : this.state.filteredStudents}
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show your full component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that you have an object with properties.

There is a few things you can do.

You can show the properties you want

Instead of trying to render the full component, you can render some prop of it

```
{this.state.search === "" ? allStudents : this.state.filteredStudents.email} // render the email string
```

What you can also do is loop over the values of the object ([`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)) and render each property

```
{this.state.search === "" ? 
    allStudents : 
    this.state.filteredStudents.map(obj => Object.values(obj)
          .map(propValue => <p>{propValue}</p>))  // render the value of each property
}
```

But please, be more clear on your question, how you want to display, what you want to display and what you have in your component.

Just keep in mind that `this.state.filteredStudents` is an object and you can't render objects.

Comment: @NicoleSCampbell if that solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and consider upvoting it. thanks!

Comment: `Object.values(this.state.filteredStudents)` is probably useless since `this.state.filteredStudents` is an array of Object. The error message refers to the objects within the array.

Comment: @EmileBergeron fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think error happened because variable allStudents is not a React object.

```js
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        filterValue: ''
    }
}

render() {
    const students = [
    {city: '', company: '', email: '', firstName: '', grades: '', id: '', lastName: '', pic: '', skill: ''}
    ] // <-- this is your array of students

    const allStudents = students.filter(student => {
        return student.firstName.includes(this.state.filterValue) || 
            student.lastName.includes(this.state.filterValue)
    }) // <-- Apply filter

    .map(student => {
        return (
            <div key={student.key}>
                <p>Name: {student.firstName} {student.lastName}</p>
                <p>Email: {email}</p>
            </div>)
    }); // <-- Wrap each element into React Component


    return (<div className="container">
          <input 
            id="search"
            name="search"
            onChange={this.handleInput} 
            placeholder="Search by name" 
            style={{width: '100%', border: '0', padding: '15px 0 7px 10px'}} 
            value={this.state.filterValue}
          />
          <hr />
          {allStudents}
        </div>)
}
```